# Redis.set works but Redis.publish don't

Tags: websocket, redis

I'm writing into a redis websocket in my django app using the following code:

```
redis.publish('fxmkt_intraday', json.dumps(
                       dict(
                           close=float(row['close']),
                           time=date_intraday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                           contract=row['object_model'].currency_name 
                       )
                   ))
```

and I'm attempting to access the ws from my graphql nodejs api using the sandbox with the following code:

```
         subscription Subscription {
           fxmkt_intraday {
             close
             contract
             time
           }
         }
```

But I'm getting this response:

```
 "errors": [
   {
     "message": "Cannot read property 'asyncIterator' of undefined",
     "locations": [
       {
         "line": 2,
         "column": 13
       }
     ],
     "path": [
       "fxmkt_intraday"
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

To troubleshoot the issue I connected to the redis in console and excecuted `PUBSUB CHANNELS *` command but no channels are being created at all, also replaced `publish` by `set` when writing into the redis and the record is being stored correctly with the key "fxmkt_intraday", so it seems not to be a connection issue with the redis.

Any hint or help will be greatly appreciated.